# PYTHON: Using Tkinter to align body of text

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("TASK")

frame1 = tk.Frame(root, bg = 'green')

line1_header = tk.Label(frame1,
text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ullum voluptua consulatu mel an, mutat \n'
'aperiri maiestatis mea ne. Ea vidit autem consulatu sit, te eum inani dictas\n'
'mollis. Eu inani legere epicurei per, omnis affert scribentur eam no, pri at \n'
'viris legere scriptorem. Per graeci habemus ut, eum no molestiae instructior. \n'
'Rebum porro vis te, ut usu vivendo pericula conclusionemque.', bg =   'green')
line1_header.pack(side = 'left', anchor = tk.N, fill = tk.X)

frame1.pack(anchor = tk.N, fill = tk.X)

root.mainloop()
```

I am wondering how I can align this body of text to the left using tkinter. I have tried side='left' and it didn't work.  What possibilities do I have for this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `justify=tk.LEFT` in your Label widget.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("TASK")

frame1 = tk.Frame(root, bg = 'green')

line1_header = tk.Label(frame1,
text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ullum voluptua consulatu mel an, mutat \n'
'aperiri maiestatis mea ne. Ea vidit autem consulatu sit, te eum inani dictas\n'
'mollis. Eu inani legere epicurei per, omnis affert scribentur eam no, pri at \n'
'viris legere scriptorem. Per graeci habemus ut, eum no molestiae instructior. \n'
'Rebum porro vis te, ut usu vivendo pericula conclusionemque.', bg =   'green',justify=tk.LEFT)
line1_header.pack(side = 'left', anchor = tk.N, fill = tk.X)

frame1.pack(anchor = tk.N, fill = tk.X)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
justify='left'
```

to the label.